# Firebase cloud messaging is not sent notification to all active users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to send firebase cloud messaging notifications and very few of them are receiving these notifications. Can someone please look into my problem.

Following is my FirebaseMessagingService code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        generateNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    }

    private void generateNotification(String body,String title)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, Home_Activity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(body);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Following is my FirebaseInstanceIdService code: Some how the token also not printing on each refresh in console

```
public class MyFirebaseServiceInstanceId extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String REG_TOKEN="REG_TOKEN";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh()
    {
        String strRecent_Token=FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if(strRecent_Token!=null)
            Log.d(REG_TOKEN,strRecent_Token);
        else
            Log.d(REG_TOKEN,"Generated null token");
    }
}
```

Following is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.udayrepo.classelearn">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">


        <activity android:name=".Home_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseServiceInstanceId">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anybody help me what i am missing here?

Comment: Can someone please look into my above mentioned problem?

Comment: Can anybody help me, why my Firebase code is not sending Cloud messaging to all mobile users? Very limited people are receiving my  messages. Can someone please let me know how to overcome this problem?